# Returning variable from onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return a variable from onreadystatechange and seem to be having trouble with scope. Even if I set a global variable, when trying to retrieve my variable after the fact, its undefined. Not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I haven't done too much work with Javascript in the past 3 years.

```
var lat;
var lon;

 window.onload = function dosomething(){

  var myRequst = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var url = "http://www.instamapper.com/api?action=getPositions&key=584014439054448247";

  myRequst.open('get', url);

  myRequst.onreadystatechange = function(){

  if ((myRequst.readyState == 4) && (myRequst.status == 200)){

  //alert(myRequst.responseText);

   var data = myRequst.responseText;
   collected=data.split(",");   //parses the data delimited by comma and put data into array

lat = collected[4];
lon = collected[5];

document.write("latitude "+lat+"<BR>\n");
document.write("latitude "+lon+"<BR>\n");

  }

  }

  myRequst.send(null);


 }

document.write(lat);
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a callback function which will handle the data. Remember AJAX stands for Asynchronous(JAX). So if after your `onreadystatechange` handling the value is not yet available is because the request did not complete at that moment.

```
myRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200) {
    (function(data) {
      // do something with the response in the variable data
    })(myRequest.responseText);
  }
}
```

Edit: also you can follow the request in the net/console tab of firebug to see exactly if an error has occured

Answer (score 1):

Is the only way of returning more than one item by using an object? Like such?

```
 myRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
 if(myRequest.readyState == 4 && myRequest.status == 200) {

  var obj;
  obj.latitude = collected[4];
  obj.longitude = collected[5];
  getdata(obj);
}
 }



function getdata(obj)
{
lat = obj.latitude;
lon = obj.longitude;
document.write(lon);
document.write(lat);
}
```